# Unresetting 4-digit number lock

Tags: combinatorics

Let there be an imaginary digital lock that verifies a simple 4-digit passcode
(in base 10 numbers, like 4281 or 3349, etc.)

**BUT** unlike other locks, ***it does not reset after a failed trial.***
That means if you enter 1823917 consecutively, you have in effect tried
1823, 8239, 2391, and 3917 (if it were a traditional lock)
i.e. If the passcode was 8239, it would open after you enter 18239.
Since it requires fewer guesses, I suppose it's not so good of a lock in terms of security,
but as a question out of pure curiosity:

What would be the most efficient method to opening this lock (the pattern of entering the numbers)

and how many numbers would you have to input in order to guarantee success?

Comment: For the second question it seems to be related with De Bruijn sequence because it gives you every $4$ string in base 10 with minimum length.

Comment: You should watch this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iPLQgXUiU14 Dr. James Grime posted this video on his channel a few years ago. He has become even more famous lately due to his work on the numberphile videos. In the video I linked, it discusses exactly this problem. He discusses three different solutions to coming up with the shortest list that checks every possibility using Hamiltonian paths, Euler paths, and also Lyndon words.